# SharePoint List Scalability

Tags: sharepoint, scalability

I am particularly interested in Document Libraries, but in terms of general SharePoint lists, can anyone answer the following...?

1. What is the maximum number of items that a SharePoint list can contain?
2. What is the maximum number of lists that a single SharePoint server can host?
3. When the number of items in the list approaches the maximum, does filtering slow down, and if so, what can be done to improve it?

Comment: I invite anyone with knowledge of recent versions of SP to update this question. I have not had cause to work with this technology for several years so am definitely not best placed to do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In SharePoint v.2:

- **Max # list items** : 2000 (per folder level)
- **Max lists per site** :  2000 is a "reasonable" number
- **Effect when we reach the limit** : Exponential degradation of performance.

More info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287743.aspx

In SharePoint v.3:

- **Max # list items** : 2000 (per view, you can have million items as long as you don't display in a single view more than 2000 items)
- **Max lists per site** : 2000 is a "reasonable" number
- **Effect when we reach the limit** : Exponential degradation of performance when we enumerate more than 2000 items using the OM. An alternative is to use Search API or CAML queries.

More info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790.aspx

Comment: I am wondering if the TechNet pages have been edited since this answer was written, as they seem to put limits in "softer" terms.

e.g. for SharePoint v.3, number of items in a list: 2,000 per view is given as " a guideline for acceptable performance... testing indicates a reduction in performance beyond two thousand items. Using indexing on a flat folder view can improve performance."

Answer (score 4):

[Link To Resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/sharepoint/archive/2007/07/25/scaling-large-lists.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The whitepaper I found most useful was linked from the resource posted by user mbowles above.
The direct link is...

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=95450&clcid=0x409

Answer (score 1):

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-SharePoint_limits.aspx

for #3:  you can index specific columns in a list, but you should still keep the sizes down.

Answer (score 1):

The exact answers have already been given, however I do feel I should add this warning:
This might be one of those situations where *if you have to ask, you can't afford it*.
So if you find yourself approaching the limits posted earlier, think long and hard about what you are trying to do, and make sure you're not doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The "2000 limit" expressed above doesn't hold.

Please take a look at [this](http://office.microsoft.com/download/afile.aspx?AssetID=AM102377231033) document for more exact answers to your questions.

I personally experimented what the document describes.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2013:

What is the maximum number of items that a SharePoint list can contain? **30.000.000.**

What is the maximum number of lists that a single SharePoint server can host? **I could not find the answer to this question.**

When the number of items in the list approaches the maximum, does filtering slow down, and if so, what can be done to improve it? **The maximum of 30.000.000 not a hard boundary, but the limit has been found by testing the product. So a performance penalty is to be expected if this limit is exceeded.**

Answers found in [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Beware, the Performance of SiteDataQuery degrades heavily he more subsites you have. A hundred subsites can take 20 seconds to query.

Answer (score 0):

There is documented guidance for Microsoft® Office SharePoint® Server 2007 regarding the maximum size of lists and list containers. For typical customer scenarios in which the standard Office SharePoint Server 2007 browser-based user interface is used, the recommendation is that a single list should not have more than 2,000 items per list container. A container in this case means the root of the list, as well as any folders in the list — a folder is a container because other list items are stored within it. A folder can contain items from the list as well as other folders, and each subfolder can contain more of each, and so on. For example, that means that you could have a list with 1,990 items in the root of the site, 10 folders that each contain 2,000 items, and so on. The maximum number of items supported in a list with recursive folders is 5 million items.

Comment: And please not there is a differance to what the documentation calls a root, and what the accepted answer calls a view.