# Sharepoint list for millions of items

Tags: sharepoint

I have to create a Help ticket kindof system & am looking for inputs to decide Sharepoint List Vs Custom DB

We have to retain 2 million tickets in the system.

We need to provide reporting againt the tickets based on date range & other criteria

We need to provide search based on date range.

Given the volume of data is Sharepoint list the right choice?

Has anyone had experience with millions of records in a sharepoint list?

Comment: update: I am using Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 2):

If you know upfront that you are going to have 2 million tickets go for custom DB. Tickets will have relations with other (busines) entities. You will want to have joins and complex queries. Use SharePoint only for documents and simple lists, SharePoint is not database.

I have experience with project on SharePoint 2010 where we trusted SP lists (10000s of items) too much in the beginning. Data ended up in custom DB.

Look [here](http://chriswoodill.blogspot.com/2009/05/sharepoint-is-not-database.html) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798319.aspx)

Comment: It's true,the list is not a database. But if you need reporting and searching function, one way is to move the data into custom database, and build reports and search function from there, but surely there will be delay between sharepoint list and reports, and it really depends on the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on version of SharePoint You are going to use.

**SharePoint 2007**

According to [this document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790.aspx), you shouldn't have more than **2000** items in a single view:

> Testing indicates a reduction in list view performance beyond two thousand entries.

So you can technically have more items there, however, you should expect some performance issues then.

The limit applies to views, so You can probably have more items in a list and keep the acceptable performance as long as you group them in views appropriately.

There is also a similar question answered here (for SharePoint 2003 and SharePoint 2007), with more helpful information: [SharePoint List Scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34728/sharepoint-list-scalability).

**SharePoint 2010 (and SharePoint 2013)**

For SharePoint 2010 (and SharePoint 2013), the limit of total number of items in a list is **30 000 000** (although it may vary depending on a specific case).

Please also take a look at other limits and restrictions mentioned in those documents.

Documents listing restrictions for various SharePoint versions:

- SharePoint 2003: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287743.aspx
- SharePoint 2007: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287790.aspx#section3
- SharePoint 2010: http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc262787%28Office.14%29.aspx#ListLibrary
- SharePoint 2013: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary